# Is $\exp(-2/X_1)$ an unbiased estimator of $\exp(-2/\theta)$?

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, expected-value, exponential-distribution, parameter-estimation

If $X_1, ..., X_n$ are i.i.d. with pdf

$$f(x\mid\theta) = \frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}\quad x>0,\, \theta>0$$

I would like to estimate $P (X_1 > 2) = e^{-2/\theta}$. I think $e^{-2/X_1}$ is a biased estimator, but I don't know how to prove. I tried to prove by definition,
$$ E(e^{-2/X_1}) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-2/x}\frac{1}{\theta}e^{-x/\theta}dx$$
but the integral is very complex to evaluate. Are there any other ways to prove it? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Maybe it is easier to estimate $\theta$ first?

Comment: For exponential distribution $\mathbb{E}(X_1)=\theta$. $e^{-2/x}$ seems concave for $x>0$, so you could try proving that and using Jensen's inequality.

Comment: There is no reason for $E[g(X_1)]=g(E[X_1])$ to hold for arbitrary function $g$. You can use Jensen's inequality to show that the estimator is biased. An unbiased estimator is simply the indicator variable of the event $\{X_1>2\}$.

Comment: There may be a particular $\theta$ (I think about $1.04238$) for which $e^{-2/X_1}$ is an unbiased estimator of $e^{-2/\theta}$

Answer (score -1):

If I understand your question, I believe you can directly compute $P\left(X_{1} \gt 2\right)$ from:

$$
P\left(X_{1} \gt 2\right)= \int_{2}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x/\theta}}{\theta}\mathrm{d}x
$$

$$
P\left(X_{1} \gt 2\right)= -\frac{1}{\theta} \theta \left[e^{-x/\theta}\right]_{2}^{\infty}=e^{-2/\theta}
$$

I hope this helps.